# Срезы в строках

Tags: python

Всем привет! вопрос: есть несколько линий в тхт, например

```
'Карман-рукав?шов'
'Карман-рукав?чтото'
'Карман-рукав?чтотоеще'
```

мне надо сделать срез из каждой строки части от символа - до символа ?, и присвоить переменной, но мой метод не работает. подскажите пожалуйста что не так:

```
srez = line ['-':'?']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш метод не может работать, т.к. строку можно индексировать только целыми числами, а не другими строками.
На выбор:

```
srez = line.split('?')[0].split('-')[1]
srez = line[line.find('-')+1:line.find('?')]
```

---

Дополню, про использование `index` вместо `find`. Если модифицировать 2-й вариант как

```
srez = line[line.find('-'):line.find('?')][1:]
```

то результат в случае отсутствия в строке `?` и/или `-` можно считать вполне корректным: в случае отсутствия `-` всегда получится пустая строка, если нет `?` но есть `-` - подстрока от `-` до конца. Считать ли такой результат верным - решать только автору вопроса, зависит от целей нахождения подстроки.

P.S. выбрасывание исключения для "невалидной" входящей строки - вполне разумный способ обработки.

Comment: srez = line[line.find('-')+1:line.find('?')] вот такой вариант подошел и работает, а подскажите по этой конструкции srez = line.split('?')[0].split('-')[1]. тут идет разделение строки по символам ? и -, но строка ведь вся присваивается переменной или я что то недопонял?

Comment: @dimahimma первый вариант тоже работает). Вопроса на вполне понял, переменной srez присваивается как  раз срез строки.

Comment: все понял, затупил

Comment: @dimahimma [используйте index() вместо find()](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647212/23044), чтобы в случае отсутствия `'-'` или `'?'` в строке получить ValueError, а не скрытый баг.

Comment: @jfs дополнил ответ

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы достать все срезы сразу из файла:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

slices = re.findall(r'\-(.*?)\?', Path('файл.txt').read_text())
```

Если только из одной строки срез получить, чтобы реализовать псевдо-код `line['-':'?']`:

```
result = line[line.index('-')+1:line.index('?')]
```

при условии, что `'?'` не встречается до `'-'` в строке (что строки похожи на примеры в вопросе). Иначе:

```
i = line.index('-')
result = line[i+1:line.index('?', i)]
```

`index()` используется вместо `find()`, чтобы получить `ValueError` на неверных входных данных (в которых или `'-'` или `'?'` отсутствуют), вместо того чтобы молча вернуть неверный результат.

Answer (score 3):

Также можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями (RegEx)

```
In [99]: data
Out[99]: ['Карман-рукав?шов', 'Карман-рукав?чтото', 'Карман-рукав?чтотоеще']

In [100]: import re

In [101]: [re.search(r'-([^\?]*)\?', x).group(1) for x in data]
Out[101]: ['рукав', 'рукав', 'рукав']
```

Хотя в данном (простом) случае - [решение от @andy.37](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647059/211923) будет быстрее/эффективнее

Comment: Не обязательно матчить все до и после искомой строки, достаточно такой регулярки: `r'-(.*?)\?'`

Comment: @insolor, спасибо! Так короче и симпатичнее получается - исправил ответ