# Как удалить последний +1 элемент в файле на языке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Привет, есть файл **numbers.txt**, в котором записаны следующие элементы

```
+1 +1 +1 +1
```

Как удалить последний `+1`. Буду благодарен, если кто-то напишет как это сделать.

Comment: Уточните, что именно надо вам удалить - последние два символа или всё что после последнего пробела? Нужен ли символ перевода строки в конце файла? Есть ли он в исходном файле? Добавьте ещё пару примеров, чтоб было понятнее

Comment: связанные вопросы [Каким образом удалить строчки выборочно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633622/23044) и [Как прочитать последнюю строку и дописать данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711318/23044)

Comment: Удалить последний +1 из файла

Comment: У вас в файле бывает только +1 и никаких других значений никогда не бывает?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вырезать только последнее вхождение `+1`, не трогая другое содержимое, которое после него может идти, можно использовать подходы из [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044) К примеру, для маленьких файлов, используя [срезы строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647212/23044):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path


text = Path('файл.txt').read_text()  # read

# cut
item = '+1'
i = text.rindex(item)  # last occurrence
text = text[:i] + text[i + len(item):]

Path('результат.txt').write_text(text)  # write
```

Как по ссылками показано, не обязательно всё содержимое файла в память читать, к примеру, [можно читать построчно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654550/23044). Можно даже [читать с конца  файла только до нужного места](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711606/23044) и выполнить аналог [`memmove(i, i + len(item))`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove), что можно реализовать с помощью [временного файла или read(chunk_size)/tell()/seek() методов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633665/23044).

---

Если после `+1` ничего не нужно сохранить в файле. Можно найти последнее вхождение `+1` в файле и обрезать (truncate) файл в этом месте:

```
with open('файл.txt', 'r+b') as file:
    i = find_last_occurence_fp(file, b'+1')
    file.truncate(i)
```

где

```
import io
import os


def find_last_occurence_fp(file, item, bufsize=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    size, s = bufsize, b''
    while item not in s:
        try:
            file.seek(-size, os.SEEK_END)
        except IOError:  # file is too small
            file.seek(0)  # rewind to beginning
            break
        finally:
            s = file.read(size)
        size *= 2  # avoid quadratic behavior
    return s.rindex(item)
```

`find_last_occurence_fp()` реализована по аналогии с упомянутой [`last_line()` функцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711606/23044), поэтому к ней применимы те же замечания о производительности.

Если элемент может быть далеко от конца файла очень большого файла, то чтобы в память не загружать лишнего, можно использовать реализацию аналогичную [`last_line()` на  основе mmap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711606/23044), не накапливая лишние данные в буфере.

Answer (score 1):

Написал построчно и с примерами данных, поэтому думаю будет понятно:

```
# Считать из файла
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()  # '+1 +1 +1 +1'
    items = text.split()  # ['+1', '+1', '+1', '+1']

# Записать в файл
with open('numbers.txt', mode='w') as f:
    items = items[:-1]  # ['+1', '+1', '+1']
    text = ' '.join(items)  # '+1 +1 +1'
    f.write(text)
```

---

Кроме того, удалить элементы из списка можно через метод `pop`, например:

```
...
items = text.split()  # ['+1', '+1', '+1', '+1']
items.pop()  # '+1'
items  #  ['+1', '+1', '+1']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [21]: # открываем файл на чтение
    ...: with open('document.txt') as file:
    ...:     # считываем содержимое файла
    ...:     # делаем из него список с помощью функции split()
    ...:     # обрезаем последний элемент [:-1]
    ...:     old_content = file.read().split()[:-1] # ['+1', '+1', '+1']
    ...:     # открываем файл на перезапись
    ...:     with open('document.txt', 'w') as update:
    ...:         # делаем из списка строку
    ...:         # разделяем её содержимое пробелами функцией ' '.join()
    ...:         # записываем в файл результат
    ...:         update.write(' '.join(old_content)) # '+1 +1 +1'
```