# Получить неизвестное слово между двумя известными?

Tags: python, работа-с-текстом

Python.
Опишу задачу.
Есть текст в котором есть строки с известными словами в начале и конце и неизвестными словами между ними.
Например:"Шёл Сергей по лесу". "Шёл ёжик по лесу" и т.д.
Как получить "Сергея", "ёжика"?

Comment: ни "Сергея" ни "ёжика" строк во вводе нет. Для фиксированных начала/конца, можно срезы использовать. См. [Срезы в строках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647053/23044)

Comment: Что значит получить? Вытащить из готового текста? Тогда регуляркой или упомянутыми срезами

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('Шёл\s(\S+)\sпо\sлесу', re.I)
unknown_word = pattern.search(text).group(0)
```